# "ffmpeg has text relocations" error in Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm building an Android video-sending application. I need the video to be compressed before being uploaded. In this case, I chose to use this Android wrapper of FFmpeg: https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java

```
FFmpeg error: WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.mycompany.myapplication/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
    ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
    built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
    configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
    libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
    libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
    libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
    libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
    libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
    libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
    libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
    libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20150104_235926.mp4':
    Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-01-04 16:00:40
    Duration: 00:01:12.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 19590 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 19364 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 26.73 fps, 26.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2015-01-04 16:00:40
    handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2015-01-04 16:00:40
    handler_name    : SoundHandle
    [libx264 @ 0x40208800] using SAR=1/1
    [libx264 @ 0x40208800] frame MB size (120x68) > level limit (1620)
    [libx264 @ 0x40208800] DPB size (1 frames, 8160 mbs) > level limit (0 frames, 8100 mbs)
    [libx264 @ 0x40208800] MB rate (219640) > level limit (40500)
    [libx264 @ 0x40208800] using cpu capabilities: none!
    [libx264 @ 0x40208800] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 0x40208800] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=28.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=2500 vbv_bufsize=1835 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
    Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.myapplication/cache/VID_20150104_235926.mp4':
    Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2500 kb/s, 26.92 fps, 10336 tbn, 26.92 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2015-01-04 16:00:40
    handler_name    : VideoHandle
    encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 4
```

Everything seemed fine when I compress small files (below 20 seconds), but when I tried to compress larger files, I seldom get the above error in the middle of the compression process, and the process was also terminated immediately. I need the application to be able to compress one minute video to about 20-35 MB.

Here is the FFmpeg command I used:

> ffmpeg -y -i  -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -b:v 2500k -minrate 2500k -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -codec:a copy

Any idea on what went wrong?
Any kind of help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Would you please paste the java code, specially where you used `cmd.add`

Comment: @HBizhi Sorry but can you elaborate? I don't remember putting `cmd.add` everywhere in my code. I just used `FFmpeg.getInstance(context).execute` as suggested in its github readme.

Comment: Any progress since then? can you post a command that worked for you?

Comment: @djzmo "This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix." is a WARNING...In my case the process continue without any other problem